# Is there a way to configure the output shape of a RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to create a RNN to guess what notes are being played on a piano, given a sound file of piano notes (WAV format). I'm currently cutting the WAV clips into ten-second chunks (2D), padding shorter sections to 10 seconds with zeroes so the input is all regular. However, when I pass in the clips to the RNN, it gives an output of one less dimension (1D) (when taking the last state - should I be taking the state series?).

I've created a simpler RNN to analyze single notes files (2D) and produce one output (1D), which has been successful. However, when trying to apply this same technique to full clips with multiple notes and notes starting/stopping it seems to break down, as I can't seem to change the output shape.

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)
    return tf.get_variable('W', dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape, initializer=initer)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0., shape=shape, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.get_variable('b', dtype=tf.float32,initializer=initial)

def RNN(x, weights, biases, timesteps, num_hidden):
    x = tf.unstack(x, timesteps, 1)

    # Define a rnn cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
    states_series, current_state = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(current_state[1], weights) + biases 
    # return [tf.matmul(temp,weights) + biases for temp in states_series]
    # does this even make sense

# x is for data, y is for targets, shapes are [index, time, frequency], [index, time, output note (s)] respectively
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = load_data() # removed test
print("Size of:")
print("- Training-set:\t\t{}".format(y_train.shape[0]))
print("- Validation-set:\t{}".format(y_valid.shape[0]))
# print("- Test-set\t{}".format(len(y_test)))

learning_rate = 0.001 # The optimization initial learning rate
epochs = 1000         # Total number of training epochs
batch_size = 100      # Training batch size
display_freq = 100    # Frequency of displaying the training results
threshold = 0.7       # Threshold for determining a "note"
num_hidden_units = 15 # Number of hidden units of the RNN

# Placeholders for inputs (x) and outputs(y)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, stepCount, num_input))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, stepCount, n_classes)) 

# create weight matrix initialized randomly from N~(0, 0.01)
W = weight_variable(shape=[num_hidden_units, n_classes])

# create bias vector initialized as zero
b = bias_variable(shape=[n_classes])

output_logits = RNN(x, W, b, stepCount, num_hidden_units)
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(output_logits)

# Define the loss function, optimizer, and accuracy, etc.
# (code removed, irrelevant)

# Creating the op for initializing all variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
global_step = 0
# Number of training iterations in each epoch
num_tr_iter = int(y_train.shape[0] / batch_size)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('Training epoch: {}'.format(epoch + 1))
    x_train, y_train = randomize(x_train, y_train)
    for iteration in range(num_tr_iter):
        global_step += 1
        start = iteration * batch_size
        end = (iteration + 1) * batch_size
        x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(x_train, y_train, start, end)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        feed_dict_batch = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch}
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)

        if iteration % display_freq == 0:
            # Calculate and display the batch loss and accuracy
            loss_batch, acc_batch = sess.run([loss, accuracy],
                                             feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)

            print("iter {0:3d}:\t Loss={1:.2f},\tTraining Accuracy={2:.01%}".
                  format(iteration, loss_batch, acc_batch))
            testLoss.append(loss_batch)
            testAcc.append(acc_batch)

    # Run validation after every epoch

    feed_dict_valid = {x: x_valid[:1000].reshape((-1, stepCount, num_input)), y: y_valid[:1000]}
    loss_valid, acc_valid = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict_valid)
    print('---------------------------------------------------------')
    print("Epoch: {0}, validation loss: {1:.2f}, validation accuracy: {2:.01%}".
          format(epoch + 1, loss_valid, acc_valid))
    print('---------------------------------------------------------')
    validLoss.append(loss_valid)
    validAcc.append(acc_batch)
```

Currently, this is outputting a 1D array of predictions, which really does not make sense in my scenario, but I'm not sure how to change it (it should be outputting predictions for each timestep - i.e. predictions of what notes are playing at each moment in time).

Comment: Is your issue resolved now. If it is not resolved yet, we can try resolving it if the complete code and the data is shared (only if it can be shared). Thanks!

Comment: I resolved it, thanks!